# Oracle isqlplus won't start and stay on starting status

Tags: oracle

I'm new on oracle and I just installed the "Oracle 10g"

but I can't access the "isqlplus" via " localhost:5560/isqlplus " it says :  "unable to connect"

so when I check the services I found everything Running but "sqlplus" is stuck on "Starting" status ... and when I tried to start it from console using : "isqlplusctl start" it says the error message shown in the picture below :

[image]

I hope you can help me solve this problem please .

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself ! and I wanna keep it here ,maybe someone else will need it later ...

so the solution is to go to "Net Configuration Assistant" in Oracle then remove the actual Listener, and add a new on again ;)

it will work fine ;) and the isqlplus will start then ;)